# How from two deviceorientation events can I find relative roll and pitch for controlling a 2D game

Tags: javascript, device-orientation

I am making a 2D maze game for mobile using the device orientation as controls. After reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation it seemed pretty simple to  take the beta and gamma values from the deviceorientation event as per the example. However, this assumes that the device will be laid down on a flat surface and rotated from there. It would be far more intuitive to take an initial set of values from the deviceorientation event when starting a level and find the relative beta and gamma between the initial and current values to ultimately determine 2D vector to control direction.

After trying to achieve this I came across a problem that for some reason the alpha, beta, gamma values seem to completely flip in the opposite direction when crossing over some threshold. This got me reading about Gimbal Locks, Quaternions, trying different JS libraries to attempt matrix transformations and all sorts. All of this is completely over my head and I'm getting nowhere with it.

So in short given an initialAlpha, initialBeta, initialGamma, currentAlpha, currentBeta, currentGamma how do I convert that into relativeBeta and relativeGamma.

The solution only needs to work on Chrome. Thanks to anyone who can help provide an example JS implementation, vanilla or with whatever library is fine.

[image: i.e. no matter what your inital orientation is movements such as this would then translate to up, down, left & right]

Comment: The MDN article you link has a toy implementation you can use to see how it actually behaves. On my phone, it looks like it might might only be useful in a face-up orientation as it seems accurate only when my phone is mostly face up. As rotation approaches edge-up, the values reported seem to have artifacts where the various rotation axis start bleeding into each other, showing rotation offsets that don't match what I'm doing with the phone.

Comment: @Ouroborus I observed the same, but to expand on what I've tried, I think the solution is to covert the alpha, beta and gamma to what's known as a Quarternion which I believe gives you orientation as an x,y,z vector and rotation w. Try this on your phone https://jbmoelker.github.io/Full-Tilt/examples/vr_test.html The values seem to be more continuous, however at certain points the values all flip negative. Maybe the solution is to take absolute values and the delta between the two points and extract the x and y components somehow but the maths is beyond me?

Comment: Additionally, I found this https://github.com/njoubert/DeviceOrientationQuaternions which is pretty close to what I'm after and similar to what I was describing. However, it seems that mapping the final x,y, z vector to a left/right/up/down value depends on your initial orientation. So close... can anyone find the final piece of the puzzle?!